# Best practice for translating Linq result to Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, collections, dictionary, windows-phone-8

I know we can use .ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Value) to convert linq resultset to Dictionary collection but I am looking for something more. I want to convert given linq result to `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>` and Here is what I am looking for:

Here is my linq query:

```
   var query = from v in dbContext.Persons
                            where !v.InActive
                            select new
                            {
                                v.PersonId,
                                v.Name,
                                v.DateOfBirth,
                            };
this.Persons = query.ToDictionaryCollection();
```

Here is what ToDictionaryCollection looks like:

```
public static IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> ToDictionaryCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection) where T : class
        {
            if (collection == null || collection.Count() == 0)
            {
                return new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            }
            Type givenType = collection.First().GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] properties = givenType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            return collection
                      .Select(entity =>
                      {
                          return properties.Select(prop => new { Key = prop.Name, Value = prop.GetValue(entity) }).ToDictionary(prop => prop.Key, prop => prop.Value);
                      });
        }
```

With the current implementation, I believe there will be a penalty of using reflection on every entity. Is there any better way of doing this, using lambda expression tree or something similar?

NOTE: Above code is for Windows Phone 8 and Windows Store 8.1 applications.

Thanks,
Binoy

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do something very similar to what `RouteValueDictionary` does in the `System.Web` world. You won't be able to get around the need to do reflection, but you would probably benefit from seeing how Microsoft solved this problem by looking at [their source code](http://pastebin.com/c1gQpBMG).

If you created a Dictionary class similar to theirs (say "`DynamicDictionary`"), then you could change your method to:

```
if (collection == null)
{
    return new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
}
return collection.Select(e => new DynamicDictionary(e));
```

And, of course, I would recommend making your method return an `IDictionary` (or even `IReadOnlyDictionary` interface, so you're not tightly coupled to a specific dictionary implementation.

Comment: great, it definitely helped to improve the code, thanks for the help, can't mark this as an answer due to low points.

Comment: unfortunately TypeDescriptor is not available in WP8

Comment: I checked the code for RouteValueDictionary and it uses TypeDescriptor in AddValues method and I was trying to update the code in same way but found that TypeDescriptor doesn't exist in WP8

Comment: @user2993678: That's unfortunate. I guess you'll have to use the `GetProperties` approach that you're already taking.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your code does exactly what you want.  Couple of minor things you could change:

Change:

`Type givenType = collection.First().GetType();`

to

`Type givenType = typeof(T);`

And also change this:

```
return properties.Select(prop => new { Key = prop.Name, Value = prop.GetValue(entity) }).ToDictionary(prop => prop.Key, prop => prop.Value);
```

to

```
return properties.ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, prop => prop.GetValue(entity));
```

There's no way to avoid reflection if you are trying to get all properties defined on a class and return their C# names.  It makes more sense to only get the values of the specific properties you know you need and to define the names elsewhere (such as in the view).  But that design choice is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a getter delegate per property and reuse those instead of calling `prop.GetValue()`.
This is benefical if the collection you're iterating over is large enough.

```
var properties = typeof (T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Select(
        p =>
        new
            {
                Name = p.Name,
                Getter = (Func<T, object>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof (Func<T, object>), p.GetGetMethod())
            })
    .ToList();

return collection.Select(i => properties.ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Getter(i)));
```